# Content assist in eclipse not available at all

Tags: eclipse, ide, content-assist, oomph

I installed eclipse with oomph - eclipse for JEE as basis + lots of other stuff defined in the oomph.setup. Now I can't activate the content assist for java:

[image]

Is it possible that I have to install something through oomph?

UPDATE
In my `org.eclipse.jdt.ui.prefs` I have:
`content_assist_disabled_computers=org.eclipse.jdt.ui.textProposalCategory$${0x0}org.eclipse.jdt.ui.javaTypeProposalCategory$${0x0}org.eclipse.jdt.ui.javaNoTypeProposalCategory$${0x0}`

Comment: Does nothing change when you `Restore Defaults`?

Comment: Are there any relevant messages in the Error Log? (**Window > Show View > Error Log**)

Comment: As nitind suggests, try `Restore Defaults`. If that doesn't work, take a look at Eclipse [Bug 515021 - ContentAssist not available](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=515021) where a user is reporting the same problem with Oomph, and details how they got Restore Defaults to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I followed 
https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=515021
and that fixed the problem.

There are 2 things one can try:

1. Java -> Editor -> Content Assist -> Advanced -> Restore Defaults and then restart eclipse
2. Close eclipse, delete workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime/.settings/org.eclipse.jdt.ui.prefs and start eclipse

The second work for me.